# kubectl patch doesn't update status subresource

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to update status subresource for a Custom Resource and I see a discrepency with curl and `kubectl patch` commands. when I use curl call it works perfectly fine but when I use `kubectl patch` command it says patched but with `no change`. Here are the command that I used

**Using Curl:**

When I connect to `kubectl proxy` and run the below curl call, it's successful and updates status subresource on my CR.

```
curl -XPATCH  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json"  --data '[{"op": "replace", "path": "/status/state", "value": "newState"}]' 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/apis/acme.com/v1alpha1/namespaces/acme/myresource/default/status'
```

**Kubectl patch command:**

Using kubectl patch says the CR is patch but with `no change` and the status sub-resource is updated.

```
$ kubectl -n acme patch myresource default --type='json' -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/status/state", "value":"newState"}]'
myresource.acme.com/default patched (no change)
```

However when I do the `kubectl patch` on the other sub-resources like `spec` it works fine. Am i missing something here?

Comment: The status subresource is often maintained by the controller and may not be directly modifiable via the API.

Comment: thanks for the response, but I can modify using the curl call and not by the kubectl patch. IIUC, they both are same while one works but the other one doesn't

Comment: It looks as if [kubectl is not able to patch the status subresource](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/564).

Comment: try this https://github.com/ulucinar/kubectl-edit-status

Answer (score 10):

As of kubectl v1.24, it is possible to patch subresources with an additional flag e.g. `--subresource=status`. This flag is considered "Alpha" but does not require enabling the feature.

As an example, with a yaml merge:

```
kubectl patch MyCrd myresource --type=merge --subresource status --patch 'status: {healthState: InSync}'
```

The [Sysdig "What's New?" for v1.24](https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-1-24-whats-new/#2590) includes some more words about this flag:

> Some kubectl commands like get, patch, edit, and replace will now contain a new flag --subresource=[subresource-name], which will allow fetching and updating status and scale subresources for all API resources.
>
> You now can stop using complex curl commands to directly update subresources.

The `--subresource` flag was promoted to "Beta" in Kubernetes v1.27 and is scheduled for promotion to "Stable" in Kubernetes v1.31 or later through [KEP-2590: graduate kubectl subresource support to stable](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/4468). The overall lifecycle of this feature can be tracked in [#2590 Add subresource support to kubectl](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/2590).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tool [kubectl-edit-status](https://github.com/ulucinar/kubectl-edit-status):

> This is a plugin for kubectl. It aims to provide an edit-status command for kubectl that allows editing of /status subresources

```
$ kubectl edit-status --help
Edit /status subresource

Usage:
  kubectl edit-status [resource] [resource-name] [flags]

Examples:

    # edit the status field of the MyResource CR named "test", which uses status subresource 
    kubectl edit-status myresource test


Flags:
      --as string                      Username to impersonate for the operation
      --as-group stringArray           Group to impersonate for the operation, this flag can be repeated to specify multiple groups.
      --cache-dir string               Default HTTP cache directory (default "/Users/alper/.kube/http-cache")
      --certificate-authority string   Path to a cert file for the certificate authority
      --client-certificate string      Path to a client certificate file for TLS
      --client-key string              Path to a client key file for TLS
      --cluster string                 The name of the kubeconfig cluster to use
      --context string                 The name of the kubeconfig context to use
  -e, --editor string                  editor to use. Either editor name in PATH or path to the editor executable. If not specified, first value of "KUBE_EDITOR" and then value of "EDITOR" environment variables are substituted and checked (default "${KUBE_EDITOR}:${EDITOR}:vi")
  -h, --help                           help for kubectl
      --insecure-skip-tls-verify       If true, the server's certificate will not be checked for validity. This will make your HTTPS connections insecure
      --kubeconfig string              Path to the kubeconfig file to use for CLI requests.
  -n, --namespace string               If present, the namespace scope for this CLI request
      --namespaced                     set to false for cluster-scoped resources (default true)
      --request-timeout string         The length of time to wait before giving up on a single server request. Non-zero values should contain a corresponding time unit (e.g. 1s, 2m, 3h). A value of zero means don't timeout requests. (default "0")
  -s, --server string                  The address and port of the Kubernetes API server
      --tls-server-name string         Server name to use for server certificate validation. If it is not provided, the hostname used to contact the server is used
      --token string                   Bearer token for authentication to the API server
      --user string                    The name of the kubeconfig user to use
```